# Integral concerning $\sin^2$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the following integral :

$$I(x;a)= \int \frac{\sin^2(x+1)}{(x+1)^a}\,dx$$

Now let the $x$ runs from $0$ to $\infty$

i.e. let

$$I_p(a)= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x+1)}{(x+1)^a}\,dx$$

Now we can see that $I_p(a)$ converges for all $\text{R}(a)>1$.

Also, for $a=1$ , $I_p(a)$ diverges .

> Question 1  : 
>   If possible , can $I_p(a)$ be represented in following way :
>
> $$I_p(a) = f(a) + \frac{C}{(a-1)}$$

Here , $f(a)$ is convergent for all $a\geqslant1$ and $C>0$

The factor $\frac{C}{(a-1)}$ explains the divergence of  $I_p(a)$ at $a=1$

> Question 2 ( important ):
>
> Analogous to Question 1 : Only replace $\sin^2(x+1)$ by $\sin^2(g(x))$ in $I_p(a)$
>
> where, $g(x)$ is an increasing function in $[1,\infty)$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: why doesn't $I(x;a)$ depend on $x$? Isn't it the antiderivative of a function of $x$?

Comment: Someone downvoted ? Is something wrong ?

Comment: Pardon the bad wording, I simply meant that $I(x,a)$ is related to the sine integral, which is known to be non-elementary. $I_p(a)$ can be written as $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(x)/x^a\,dx$ and Question1 has the trivial answer $f=I_p$ and $C=0$. Question2 can be tackled through substitutions and integration by parts, assuming the continuity and unbounded-ness of $g(x)$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I mentioned $C>0$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, use the double angle formula to have
$$\sin^2(x+1)=\frac 12 \left(1-\cos(2(x+1))\right)$$ Then use $\cos(t)=\frac {e^{it}+e^{-it}}2$ to face the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

You should end with something like
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{ \sin ^2(x+1)} {(x+1)^{a}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2 (a-1)}-\frac{1}{4} (E_a(2 i)+E_a(-2 i))$$ provided $\Re(a)>1$.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici thank you for the answer .

Comment: @Bambi If you think it's a satisfactory answer, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted (by clicking the tick mark below the vote buttons).

Comment: @YiFan I tried to upvote but not enough reputation ( so only recorded ,not shown) and I'm looking for any further comment on question 2 as it's my main concern .

Comment: @Bambi Sure, just making sure you knew the mechanics of the site :) Welcome to MSE!

Comment: @YiFan thank you . (And also thank you for supporting earlier )